# Запись каждого значение коллекции в json файл

Tags: c#, json, файлы, консоль

**Добрый день!**

Вопрос такой!
Пытаюсь записать все элементы коллекции в файл json, но почему-то записываеться только последний элемент коллекции в файл!

*Вот код, который я использую для вывода в консоль и запись их в файл:*

```
        foreach (var m in listHashRepo)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = System.ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine(m);

            JObject wcomm = new JObject(new JProperty("url", m));
            File.WriteAllText("files.json", wcomm.ToString());
        }
```

*В файле записываеться только последний элемент:*

```
{"url": "e92bc448678ef499cfeabb3df93ea7adad47f747"}
```

*А хотелось, чтобы он записывал всё. Примерно так:*

```
{"url": "24gfd5ff7f9fd5gs98uf349k31u6g2134io6h345"}
{"url": "89fsd898c23993d9571cmvfnjh450cnklfhijrwi"}
{"url": "43j24j5390fsnto0g775jli43omh5oh632ji5p5p"}
{"url": "e92bc448678ef499cfeabb3df93ea7adad47f747"}
```

Помогите разобраться, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Неудивительно, вы же переписываете файл заново на каждой итерации. Пожалуйста, поместите ваш код не в виде картинки, а в виде текста, и дайте пример того, какой выходной формат файла вы хотите.

Comment: @VladD Поправил вопрос!

Comment: Но то, что вы хотите, это же не JSON! JSON-формат выглядел бы как-то так: `[ {"url": "24gfd5ff7f9fd5gs98uf349k31u6g2134io6h345"},
{"url": "89fsd898c23993d9571cmvfnjh450cnklfhijrwi"} ]`.

Comment: @VladD Да, не поставил скобки, извиняюсь.

Comment: Цикл foreach предназначен только для перебора (чтения), а не для записи!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то, чтобы сериализовать коллекцию, можно написать просто

```
File.WriteAllText("files.json", hashes, Formatting.Indented);
```

(**не** в цикле!) Это произведёт такой JSON:

```
[
  "24gfd5ff7f9fd5gs98uf349k31u6g2134io6h345",
  "89fsd898c23993d9571cmvfnjh450cnklfhijrwi",
  "43j24j5390fsnto0g775jli43omh5oh632ji5p5p",
  "e92bc448678ef499cfeabb3df93ea7adad47f747"
]
```

Если вам нужно ещё и `"url"`, это делается немного сложнее:

```
File.WriteAllText(
    "files.json",
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        hashes.Select(hash => new { url = hash }),
        Formatting.Indented));
```

Результат будет такой:

```
[
  {
    "url": "24gfd5ff7f9fd5gs98uf349k31u6g2134io6h345"
  },
  {
    "url": "89fsd898c23993d9571cmvfnjh450cnklfhijrwi"
  },
  {
    "url": "43j24j5390fsnto0g775jli43omh5oh632ji5p5p"
  },
  {
    "url": "e92bc448678ef499cfeabb3df93ea7adad47f747"
  }
]
```

---

Из комментариев: если у вас на самом деле *две* последовательности, их можно объединить при помощи `Zip`:

```
var hashes = new[]
{
    "24gfd5ff7f9fd5gs98uf349k31u6g2134io6h345",
    "89fsd898c23993d9571cmvfnjh450cnklfhijrwi",
    "43j24j5390fsnto0g775jli43omh5oh632ji5p5p",
    "e92bc448678ef499cfeabb3df93ea7adad47f747"
};
var urls = new[]
{
    "https://github.com/VladislavsGeidans/wikicar.git",
    "https://github.com/VladislavsGeidans/1.git",
    "https://github.com/VladislavsGeidans/2.git",
    "https://github.com/VladislavsGeidans/3.git",
};

File.WriteAllText(
    "files.json",
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        hashes.Zip(urls, (hash, url) => new { hash, url }),
        Formatting.Indented));
```

Результат:

```
[
  {
    "hash": "24gfd5ff7f9fd5gs98uf349k31u6g2134io6h345",
    "url": "https://github.com/VladislavsGeidans/wikicar.git"
  },
  {
    "hash": "89fsd898c23993d9571cmvfnjh450cnklfhijrwi",
    "url": "https://github.com/VladislavsGeidans/1.git"
  },
  {
    "hash": "43j24j5390fsnto0g775jli43omh5oh632ji5p5p",
    "url": "https://github.com/VladislavsGeidans/2.git"
  },
  {
    "hash": "e92bc448678ef499cfeabb3df93ea7adad47f747",
    "url": "https://github.com/VladislavsGeidans/3.git"
  }
]
```

Comment: А ввод двух значений из разных коллекций реализовывать как?

Comment: Чтобы было так: 
http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/02/36e0aa16be83c5c83b9c56c18559c1d0.png

Comment: @VladislavsGeidans: У вас две отдельные коллекции?

Comment: @VladislavsGeidans: Дописал ответ.

Comment: Таким методом, у меня получаеться: http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/02/07d118aeb51b93e48a3f7a4bb84c09ef.png

Comment: @VladislavsGeidans: Тогда дайте ваш код (желательно, в текстовом виде)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53753/discussion-between-vladislavs-geidans-and-vladd).

Answer (score 3):

Нужен некоторый анализ, различающий запись первого объекта и последующих.

```
File.Delete("files.json");
foreach (var m in listHashRepo)
{
  Console.ForegroundColor = System.ConsoleColor.Cyan;
  Console.WriteLine(m);

  JObject wcomm = new JObject(new JProperty("url", m));
  if (!File.Exists("files.json"))  
    File.WriteAllText("files.json", "[" + wcomm.ToString());
  else
    File.AppendAllText("files.json", "," + wcomm.ToString());
}
File.AppendAllText("files.json", "]");
```